# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error while doing cs50 lab

Tags: c, cs50

when I type ./scrabble and enter Player 1 and 2's words, the result is segmentation fault(core dumped). I looked at other similar solutions and they had no errors, so where did i make the mistake.

```
 int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    
    int compute_score(string word);
    
    int main(void)
    {
        // Get input words from both players
        string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
        string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");
    
        // Score both words
        int score1 = compute_score(word1);
        int score2 = compute_score(word2);
    
        // TODO: Print the winner
        if ( score1 > score2 )
        {
            printf("Player 1 Wins\n");
        }
        else if (score1 < score2)
        {
            printf("player 2 Wins\n");
        }
        else if (score1 == score2)
        {
            printf("Tie\n");
        }
    }
    
    int compute_score(string word)
    {
        // TODO: Compute and return score for string
        int score= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        {
            if islower(word)
            {
                score = POINTS[(word[i])-65];
            }
            if isupper(word)
            {
                score = POINTS[(word[i])-97];
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

Comment: This program contains some wrong syntax and can't be compiled, let alone segfaulting.

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? Read this: [mcve] and then [Edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Don't hard-code values like `65` and `97`, use `'A'` and `'a'`. And the problem is that you got these values backwards, for lowercase it should be `97`.

Comment: You also should be adding to score, not reassigning it: `score += POINTS[...];`

Answer (score 2):

You're subtracting the wrong values from the character codes, because `65` is the ASCII code for `A`, not `a`. Avoid problems like this by using character literals rather than ASCII codes.

The argument to `islower()` and `isupper()` must be the current character in the word `word[i]`, not the whole string `word`.

You're also not adding to the score, you're overwriting it in the loop. So the score will just be for the last letter in the word. Use `+=` to add to the variable instead of `=` to assign it.

```
    int compute_score(string word)
    {
        int score= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        {
            if islower(word[i])
            {
                score += POINTS[(word[i])-'a'];
            }
            else if isupper(word[i])
            {
                score += POINTS[(word[i])-'A'];
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

Comment: I understand my issue for the wrong values for ASCII codes, but i dont understand how to add the score instead of overwriting it in the loop?

Comment: Using `score +=` instead of `score =`, as I show in the answer.

Comment: I tried using score+= instead of score = and im still getting an error for seg fault

Comment: `=` or `+=` has nothing to do with the seg fault. The sge fault was due to subtracting the wrong amount.

Comment: Okay, but whats causing the seg fault

Comment: Another problem: `islower(word)` should be `islower(word[i])`. I just added that correction to the answer. You should have gotten a compiler warning about that.